# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable get not updated value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, environment-variables

IDE: visual studio 2019
Project: Console application
Language: C#
FW: .NET core
Problem description:

1. Using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() method to get the environment variable (defined both in the User variables and in the System Variable).
2. Get the defined value.
3. Change the value of the key, both in the User variables and in the System Variable.
4. Rerun debugging in the VS - use the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() method - receiving the **OLD** value.

Comment: "Change the value of the key, both in the User variables and in the System Variable." Did you restart VS after that? If not, that's probably the issue - I suspect the child process is inheriting the environment variables from VS, which was started before you changed them.

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet, how are you updating the value thus the approach.

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron - I updated it not by using the code, but through the Windows Environment variables utility

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. VS only reads environment variables when it starts, so if you change them after starting VS, it will show you the values that were set when it started.

Painful in your case, but that's the way it is I'm afraid.